# Replace paragraphs with textarea's containing existing paragraph value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to find all paragraphs within a document and replace them with textarea's where the text inside the textarea is the original content. I've tried jquery's .replaceWith() and .contents() but neither work.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('p,div').replaceWith("<textarea rows='4'>" + $(this).text() + "</textarea>");
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p>first</p>
<p>second</p>
<p>third</p>
</body>

</html>
```

AND

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('p,div').replaceWith("<textarea rows='4'>" + $(this).contents().filter(function () { return this.nodeType === 3 }).text() + "</textarea>");
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>first</p>
    <p>second</p>
    <p>third</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is due to the scope of `this`. For it to work you need to provide `replaceWith()` with a function that runs on each matched element in the set. From this function you just need to return the HTML to replace the original element with. Try this:

```js
$('p, div').replaceWith(function() {
  return '<textarea rows="4">' + $(this).text() + '</textarea>';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>first</p>
<p>second</p>
<p>third</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$(this)` will be referring to the document and not to the current html element form the selection. 
You can loop through all elements instead:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('p,div').each(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
    $this.replaceWith("<textarea rows='4'>" + $this.text() + "</textarea>");
   });
 });
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/9vuckxtu/)